# Using Taxonomies with Vote It Up plugin chart

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

I am using the Vote Me Up plugin  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/ on my site.
I have the MostVotedAllTime function showing the top 10 posts. Currently this displays the Post Title only. I am wondering if it is possible to display a custom taxonomy associated with the post here.

for example it is a chart showing music albums where the post title is the album title. I have a taxonomy called artist which i would also like to display in the chart.

Does anybody know if this is possible or if there are any better plugins for this?

Here is the code for the MostVotedAlltime() function

```
function MostVotedAllTime_Widget() {
$a = SortVotes();
//Before

?>
<div class="votewidget">
<div class="title">Most Voted</div>
<?php
$rows = 0;

//Now does not include deleted posts
$i = 0;
while ($rows < get_option('voteiu_widgetcount')) {
if ($a[0][$i][0] != '') {
        $postdat = get_post($a[0][$i][0]);
    if (!empty($postdat)) {
        $rows++;

        if (round($rows / 2) == ($rows / 2)) {
            echo '<div class="fore">';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="back">';
        }
        echo '<div class="votecount">'.$a[1][$i][0].' '.Pluralize($a[1][$i][0], 'votes', 'vote').' </div><div><a href="'.$postdat->guid.'" title="'.$postdat->post_title.'">'.$postdat->post_title.'</a></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
if ($i < count($a[0])) {
$i++;
} else {
break; //exit the loop
}
}
//End
?>
```

Comment: Add the code for the `MostVotedAllTime()` function.

Comment: Hi, edited post to include code for the MostVotedAllTime() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_the_term_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) to print the assigned terms.

Example:

```
    echo '<div class="votecount">' . /* stripped */ . '</div>';
    echo echo get_the_term_list( $postdat->ID, 'taxonomyname', 'Taxonomy Label: ', ', ', '' );
    echo '</div>';
```

Replace `'taxonomyname'` and `'Taxonomy Label: '` with the values you actually need.

Comment: thanks.Just tried this however it displays the same taxonomy value for each post and not the one that is associated with the post

Comment: Changing to  get_the_term_list( $postdat->ID, 'artist', ' ', ', ', '' );  seems to have worked :)